# How do I read a file line by line in Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file

I have a file that i want to read(words.txt). I would like to save it in an array, but it is too long to include in the file, so I put it in a separate file. I can use a URL to get it, but I also have the file in the same folder as the javascript file. What would be the simplest way to do this without using jQuery or Node.js?

Comment: @AlonEitan that doesnt explain how to do it in chunks

Comment: I decided to do some sorting in python and then use it. I think this will help with the file size problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you are trying to read a very large file in chunks, so as not to crash the browser with too much memory, am I right? If not, let me know.

While in general, to read it "line by line", people ([How to use Javascript to read local text file and read line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331546/how-to-use-javascript-to-read-local-text-file-and-read-line-by-line)) usually just load the entire file, then split it by `"\n"`, but that fails to address the issue of crashing the browser with an overtly large file.

What you're looking for is the [progress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/progress_event) for the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), or [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event) classes, depending on whether you are fetching local, user-selected files or files from a server.

It should allow you to read parts of a larger file in chunks. As the chunks come in, you can keep track of the new line characters (`\n`), and keep each set of text in a new array, accordingly.

For keeping track of the chunks, [XMLHttpRequest chunked response, only read last response in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635919/xmlhttprequest-chunked-response-only-read-last-response-in-progress), if you're fine with keeping an accumulated amount of response data in memory, if not you can try the array-buffer approach mentioned at [How to write javascript in client side to receive and parse `chunked` response in time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789703/how-to-write-javascript-in-client-side-to-receive-and-parse-chunked-response-i), or even better, to use the ReadableStream class as mentioned in an answer there, together with fetch.

Based on that answer as well as others, I've attempted to put together a function which will give you a callback each line is read, and read the total URL by chunks, even though the chunks themselves may be slightly more than 1 line at a time, but it's the closest I could think of with client-side JavaScript, let me know if it works:

```
function readLineByLine(url, callback) {
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        let fetchReader = response.body.getReader(),
            decoder = new TextDecoder(),
            currentLineData = "",
            totalLines = [];
        fetchReader.read()
        .then(function readData(progress) {

            let thisJustInSomeData = decoder.decode(
                progress.value || "",
                {
                    stream: !progress.done
                }
            ),
                lines = thisJustInSomeData.split("\n");

            if(lines.length < 2) {
                currentLineData += lines[0];
            } else {
                lines.forEach((x, i, a) => {
                    currentLineData += x;
                    totalLines.push(currentLineData);

                    if(i < lines.length - 1) {
                        currentLineData = "";
                    }
                });
            }

            totalLines.forEach(line => {
                callback({line});
            });

            totalLines = []
            if(progress.done) {
                callback({done: progress.done})
                return;
            }

            return readData();
        })
    });
}
```

then to call it

```
readLineByLine("someURLorTxtFileWithLotsOfLines", line => console.log(line));
```